# update the state of a JPA object in coherence cache with out having to update it in database

Tags: oracle-coherence

We are having a requirement in which we want to update the state of a JPA object in coherence cache with out having to update it in database.

We are currently using query.setHint( QueryHints.QUERY_REDIRECTOR, new IgnoreDefaultRedirector() ); to impliment caching .

Any Example to achieve this is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using TopLink Grid (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/tl-grid-097210.html).

In that scenario TopLink Grid controls the usage of Coherence caches, including how many separate caches are used (it uses a separate cache per entity type; the cache names by default are the unqualified names of the entity classes).  The keys of the Coherence caches are the IDs of the entities, and the values are the actual entity objects (possibly wrapped, see below), not "CacheEntry" objects from which entities are constructed, as is the case with Hibernate second-level caching.

The only way I know to update the state of a JPA entity cached in Coherence by TopLink Grid is to violate the encapsulation of TopLink Grid - i.e. bypass the JPA API, and use the Coherence API directly, with knowledge of how TopLink Grid uses Coherence caches.  For example you could use a ConditionalPut processor (with the condition being AlwaysFilter.INSTANCE), or perhaps a PofUpdater processor, to update your entity.

But be aware that there are some complexities to do with relationships between entities.  If an entity has relationship mappings, the value in the Coherence cache for that entity is an instance of a generated class wrapping the actual entity and holding relationship information.  So you'll have to account for that when using the Coherence API directly on a TopLink Grid cache (see http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/coherence/COHIG/tlg_integrate.htm#BGBCDFFJ).